# mongo: how to project array elements excluding some values?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongo 3.6. How do I return array items which are NOT in a certain list of values?

Here's the doc:

```
{
    "_id" : "myId",
    "myList" : [ 
        "a", 
        "b", 
        "c"
    ]
}
```

here's the query, which returns only the FIRST match:

```
db.getCollection('Item').find({_id:"myId"}, {
    myList:{ $elemMatch:{
        $not: { $in:["a"] }
    }}
})
```

result:

```
{
    "_id" : "myId",
    "myList" : [ "b" ]
}
```

Expected result - how do I change the query above to return ALL matches for 'not in ["a"]'? Something that yields:

```
{
    "_id" : "myId",
    "myList" : [ "b", "c" ]
}
```

Any idea why items are missing?

Answer (score 1):

User aggregate with

> $filter

as below to get expected output:

```
db.getCollection("Item").aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                list: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$myList",
                        as: "item",
                        cond: { $ne: ["$$item", "a"] },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ]);
```

Comment: see my comment to @AlexisG above

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with an aggregate

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "myId"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      myList: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$myList",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$item",
                [
                  "a"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d0etMx6ppxG)

Comment: dude you snatched my answer :(

Comment: doesn't seem to work. yields only ["c"] instead of ["b","c"] for some reason. Note I'm on mongo 3.6 and not on v5.0 like the playground

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result using Aggregation Pipeline...

```
db.getCollection("Item").aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      list: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$myList",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$item",
              "a"
            ]
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: I deliberately need to use {$not:{$in}} rather than $ne. When I try this, I get similar result, i.e. $not:{$in: ["$$item",["c"]]} would yield only ["b"] and not ["a","b"]

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be the only thing that works on Mongo 3.6 for me, although @AlexisG's solution works in the Mongo v5 playground as well but not on my Mongo 3.6 :-/

```
db.getCollection('Item').aggregate([
    {$match:{_id:"myId"}},
    {$project:{myList:1}},
    {$unwind:{path:"$myList"}},
    {$match:{myList:{$not:{$in:["a"]}}}}
])
```